# Groovy-based Spring Boot task choking on configured cron

Tags: spring-boot, groovy

Not sure if this is purely a Spring Boot issue, purely a Groovy issue, or a problem arising from using Groovy to build a Spring Boot app. I have a Spring Boot background task that -- in production -- I want running once an hour:

```
@Component
class MyTask {
    @Scheduled(cron = "${tasks.mytask.cron}")
    void doSomething() {
        // blah whatever
    }
}
```

In my `application.yml` file I have:

```
logging:
  config: 'logback.groovy'
server:
  port: 9200
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
spring:
  cache:
    type: none
myapp:
  detailsMode: ${detailsMode:Terse}
  verification: 5
  tasks:
    mytask:
      cron: '0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *'
```

However for local development I want to be able to change the cron expression (for testing, etc.). When I go to compile this I get:

```
Expected '$tasks.mytask.cron' to be an inline constant of type java.lang.String in @org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled
@ line 31, column 23.
      @Scheduled(cron = "${tasks.mytask.cron}")
```

Any ideas what I need to do to fix this? I need an externally-configurable value like `tasks.mytask.cron` that I can define in my app properties/YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myapp:
  detailsMode: ${detailsMode:Terse}
  verification: 5

tasks:
  mytask:
    cron: '0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?'
```

or

```
@Scheduled(cron = '${myapp.tasks.mytask.cron}')
```

also notice that your cron format is incorrect

Comment: Thanks @dawid (+1) but this is a **compiler error** not runtime. I'm thinking maybe Groovy doesn't like [GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.10/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html)-style expressions inside of annotations?

Comment: right, groovy then `@Scheduled(cron = '${myapp.tasks.mytask.cron}')`

Comment: Basically `"someting"` mean gstring - for gstring $ is groovy variable - you don't want groovy variable - you want Spring property - thats why need to replace it with regular String - in groovy - `'someting' `